# iOS: SVProgressHUD not displaying in centre when i use setContainerView

Tags: ios, svprogresshud

I am using SVProgressHUD for loader. When i use setContainerView method the loader is not displaying in centre. Can any one help me out.

Used below code to show Loader

```
 + (void)showLoadingHUDForView:(UIView *)view {
    if (view != nil) {
        [SVProgressHUD setRingThickness:3.0];
        [SVProgressHUD setContainerView:requiredView];
        [SVProgressHUD setDefaultStyle:SVProgressHUDStyleDark];
        [SVProgressHUD setDefaultMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeClear];
        [SVProgressHUD show];
    }
}
```

Comment: R u calling this function in `viewdidload` method

Comment: yes @Maddy some places i am calling this from viewWillAppear, viewdidload. From these methods i am calling one more method that contains api request and response. When ever i call request then calling show HUD method.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the progressHUD's offset from center, like so:

```
let containerOrigin = requiredView.origin
SVProgressHUD.setOffsetFromCenter(UIOffset(horizontal: -containerOrigin.x, vertical: -containerOrigin.y))
```

If your **requiredView** is contained in another view, you will have to take in consideration all the parent views in the hierarchy, because progressHUD offset seems to be relative to the app's **window**.